# Ionic application connection with Mantra biometric device

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, capacitor

I want to develop an Ionic Android Application where the user will authenticate by scanning fingerprint via Mantra device.

Answer (score 1):

You can develop an Ionic app for that purpose, but it would take some extra work as there are no plugins available.

If you want to integrate your app with a Mantra device you need an SDK provided by them. I did some research and it looks like they have an **Android** SDK available [here](https://servico.mantratecapp.com/Home/SDK.html), but their documentation seems very poor.

If you want to develop an Ionic Android Application using their SDK you would have to develop your own cordova (or better yet, capacitor) plugin. It is not that hard to do, as you can find some useful tutorials like [this one](https://devdactic.com/build-capacitor-plugin/).